# PHP: Using google map embed iframe and pulling a postcode from the database to display

Tags: php, google-maps, iframe

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTm-3Cduafw

Above is basically what I am after but I have tried everything to get it working...I want to pull the postcode from the database and use that, instead of a full address. Its so each user has a different map position, based on what postcode is stored in their account, in the database.

Im using dreamweaver, I have brought in the recordset and the php bit that I am trying to use is below.

```
<?php echo "$postcode";?>
```

Above is the snippet and below is what i have so far

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<?php echo "$postcode";?>&amp;aq=&amp;t=h&amp;g=<?php echo "$postcode";?>&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=<?php echo "$postcode";?>&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I appreciate this isn't a recent question, but it's worth bearing in mind that if readers need to see a YouTube video to understand the question, you'll not get many answers, and it _may_ be deleted as too dependent on an external brittle link (the video may not be around for ever).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `&` instead of `&amp;`, because $amp; is the html tag

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! Sadly that didn't work. The code still works but it still shows the wrong location hmm...

Comment: Probably its just a problem with the location, maybe there are multiple position called so. Or the Geo-Code is wrong

Comment: still no luck...anyone know if it is possible this way? tried with a few different locations!

Comment: @EddynandFuchs: as far as I know, the ampersand in links should be escaped just the same as ampersands in text. The W3C HTML Validator will pick this up as an error, and it risks turning following text into an HTML entity accidentally.